# Managing drag in React on-off component

Tags: javascript, react.js, user-interface

I made a on-off switch to be more fluent in React and added touch functionality to it.

[image]

The idea is to have it independent of the state management library/logic, and be easy to import into a project, regardless of the state managing being used.

**My question is:** is the touch implementation (and overall React logic) correct, and following good practise? or should the touch event handlers and changing of the element's `.style.left` be handled in another way to follow React's way of thinking?

You can see a [online demo here](https://rawgit.com/SergioCrisostomo/react-onoff-switch/1.0.0/demo/demo.html).
The GitHub repo with all [source code is here](https://github.com/SergioCrisostomo/react-onoff-switch).

The component code:

```
export default class OnOff extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const active = !!props.initialValue;
        this.state = {
            ...componentDefaults,
            ...props,
            on: active, // false if not set
            activeColorWidth: active ? 1 : 0.6,
            buttonPosition: active ? 0.4 : 0,
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.onChange = props.onChange || (() => {});
        this.onPointerDown = this.onPointerDown.bind(this);
        this.onDrag = this.onDrag.bind(this);
        this.onDragEnd = this.onDragEnd.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(state) {
        const val = typeof state == 'boolean' ? state : !this.state.on;
        this.setState({
            on: val,
            buttonPosition: val ? 0.4 : 0,
            activeColorWidth: val ? 1 : 0.6
        },
            () => this.onChange(this.state.on) // callback to parent Component
        );
    }

    getPointerCoords(e){
        return e.pageX || e.touches[0].pageX;
    }

    onPointerDown(e){
        stopEvent(e);
        this.touchDown = this.getPointerCoords(e.nativeEvent) - parseInt(e.target.style.left, 10);
        window.addEventListener('ontouchend' in window ? 'touchend' : 'mouseup', this.onDragEnd);
    }

    onDrag(e){
        if (!this.touchDown) return;
        else this.dragged = true;
        stopEvent(e);

        // 0.4 and 0.6 are related to proportions where 1 is the width
        // 0.4 is the most left point of the buttonPosition
        // 0.6 is the most right point, so the active color fills the whole background behind the button

        const positionNow = this.getPointerCoords(e.nativeEvent);
        let diff = (positionNow - this.touchDown) / this.state.width;
        const maxDragDistance = 0.4;
        if (diff < 0) diff = 0;
        else if (diff > maxDragDistance) diff = maxDragDistance;
        const pos = 0.6 + diff;

        this.setState({
            buttonPosition: diff,
            activeColorWidth: pos
        });
    }

    onDragEnd(e){
        stopEvent(e);
        if (!this.touchDown) return;

        window.removeEventListener('ontouchend' in window ? 'touchend' : 'mouseup', this.onDragEnd);
        const newState = this.dragged ? this.state.buttonPosition > 0.2 : !this.state.on;
        this.handleChange(newState);
        this.touchDown = this.dragged = null;
    }

    render() {
        const on = this.state.on;

        const active = setStyles({
            ...onBackground,
            width: this.state.activeColorWidth,
            background: this.state.activeColor
        }, this.state.width);

        const passive = setStyles({
            ...offBackground,
            background: this.state.passiveColor
        }, this.state.width);

        const button = setStyles({
            ...buttonStyle,
            left: this.state.buttonPosition,
            boxShadow: `inset 0 0 0 1px ${on ? this.state.activeColor : grey}, 0 2px 4px ${grey}`,
            background: this.state.buttonColor
        }, this.state.width);

        return (
            <div style={{position: 'relative', height: 0.6 * this.state.width}}>
                <div style={passive}/>
                <div style={active}/>
                <div
                    onMouseMove={this.onDrag}
                    onTouchMove={this.onDrag}
                    onTouchStart={this.onPointerDown}
                    onMouseDown={this.onPointerDown}
                    onMouseOut={this.onDragEnd}
                    style={button}/
                    >
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it would be better to handle `onMouseUp={this.onDragEnd}`? Also instead of `const componentDefaults` you can use `OnOff.defaultProps`. And if you want to share this component for other people, I recommend to specify `OnOff.propTypes`, it makes the code more stable and resistant.

At the whole seems good, works on desktop and mobile as well.

Comment: Thanks for feedback! When you say `OnOff.defaultProps` do you mean `this.defaultProps = ...` or `OnOff.prottype.defaultProps = ...`, or some other way? About `OnOff.propTypes` not sure what that is, will google for it.

Comment: About `onMouseUp` I have a handler `window.addEventListener('ontouchend' in window ? 'touchend' : 'mouseup', this.onDragEnd);` since the mousedown/touchdown can end outside the button (if we drag too long) I opted to have it in the `window`. Thoughts about that?